# Get RecyclerView orientation in custom view

Tags: java, android, android-recyclerview, android-custom-view

I'm trying to create a custom view extending `RecyclerView`. In my custom view, I have some things to do according to the `RecyclerView` orientation (horizontal or vertical).

Unfortunately, I don't find any way to know and get the `RecyclerView` orientation.

Is it even possible to do?

I know that `RecyclerView` orientation is defined in its `LayoutManager`. Maybe it is impossible to get this `LayoutManager` information?

Thank you in advance for any help you can provide.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok I just found the solution:

```
LayoutManager.getProperties(context, attrs, 0, 0).orientation
```

This line returns either **0** or **1** if the recyclerView is respectively **HORIZONTAL** or **VERTICAL**

Just in case, here is my customView constructor:

```
     public CustomRecyclerView(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) {
            super(context, attrs);

            if (LayoutManager.getProperties(context, attrs, 0, 0).orientation == 0)
                Log.d("recycler orientation", "horizontal");
            else if (LayoutManager.getProperties(context, attrs, 0, 0).orientation == 1)
                Log.d("recycler orientation", "vertical");
     }
```

Answer (score 5):

If your layout manager is LinearLayoutManager, then you can use this function.

```
(recyclerView.layoutManager as LinearLayoutManager).orientation
```

It returns `LinearLayout.HORIZONTAL` or `LinearLayout.VERTICAL`

Comment: Works also for `GridLayoutManager` since it inherits from `LinearLayoutManager`

Answer (score 0):

Unless you have a custom `LayoutManager`, the orientation info makes sense only for `LinearLayoutManager` and its subclasses (`GridLayoutManager`). In this case you can use the `LinearLayoutManager.getOrientation` method.

From the doc

```
  Returns the current orientation of the layout.
```